# How to usb tether a wifi network using iphone

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, usb, tethering

I have installed windows 10 on my Mac and the Wi---Fi is interfering with the Bluetooth so I've turned off the Wi-Fi on the Mac.

My iPhone is connected to the Wi-Fi so I want to usb-tether the Wi-Fi to my mac through my iPhone.

But I have noticed that usb-tether is using cellular connection instead of Wi-Fi which costs me money.

Is there a way to usb-tether a Wi-Fi network instead of cellular network?

Android happily do this. After all it is common sense to tether the gateway.

Comment: this is ridiculous, my desktop Wifi adapator stopped working. So I had to tether my mobiles net to desktop. My Broadband Wifi is 50 times faster then my mobile. Also My daily cellular internet is capped and I have to download 60GB Game. Now What Do I Do? I had to watch Game of thrones S8E3 on 5inch mobile then on 50 inch screen because of above issue, because I cast my computer to TV and can not cast my Mobile to TV.

Answer (score 3):

The personal hotspot feature uses the cellular data connection. It's currently not possible to share the Wi-Fi connection from your iPhone without jailbreaking.

If your iPhone is jailbroken you can use Bridge Mode with [MyWi](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.mywi4/).

Comment: this is ridiculous, my desktop Wifi adapator stopped working. So I had to tether my mobiles net to desktop. My Broadband Wifi is 50 times faster then my mobile. Also My daily cellular internet is capped and I have to download 60GB Game. Now What Do I Do?

Comment: I had to watch Game of thrones S8E3 on 5inch mobile then on 50 inch screen because of above issue, because I cast my computer to TV and can not cast my Mobile to TV.

Comment: @abksharma Without Jailbreaking, there’s nothing you can do. You can provide feedback to Apple https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html